# How to create a filled screen ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to create a activity that looks like the gallery or whatsapp image view

I want the image to got displayed in its normal size and allow users to zoom in and out inside the ImageView so he can see the details of the image (which will contain text so i need to have zooming)
Please help cause i need this fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library provides zooming `ImageView`s.

Comment: well but I want to create the gallery style to show and hide the action bar on click

Answer (score 0):

Here is another great library i use.

https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

Simply use this in xml instead of regular ImageView like this:

```
<your_package_name.ImageViewTouch
    android:id="@+id/image_hq"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_hq"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />
```